# How to change the appearance of ARSCNDebugOptions FeaturePoints?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Is there a way to change the appearance (size, color, etc) of the feature points in ARKit easily? (After setting `debugOptions` in the sceneView to `ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints`  I'm thinking I might have to iterate over the `rawFeaturePoints` and manually add custom objects into the scene at those points.

Comment: Maybe this could also be interesting: https://github.com/BlackMirrorz/ARPointCloud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As its name suggests, `ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints` is a tool to aid in debugging your app. Because the size and color of feature point indicators aren't essential to knowing where feature points are (for the sake of making sure your app is behavior correctly), Apple doesn't offer API to change their appearance. (Any more than they offer APIs for changing the colors of bounding boxes, physics shapes, and other indicators available in SceneKit [debug options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scndebugoptions).)

If you want to create your own visualization for feature points, you'll need to do exactly as you suggest: read the `rawFeaturePoints` from the current `ARFrame` and use those to position content in the SceneKit scene. You might do this by creating a bunch of nodes with geometry and setting their positions. You might also look into whether it's easy to pass the entire buffer of points to create an `SCNGeometry` that renders in [point-cloud mode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017-604/?time=2940).